# Proper SqlAlchemy query using contains_eager

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a query that I have found a working solution for. I am not sure if I am performing the query properly and I was hoping to find out. The tables appear as follows:

[image: owner]

The query is:

```
q = session.query(Person).outerjoin(PetOwner).join(Animal).options(contains_eager("petowner_set"), contains_eager("petowner_set.animal"))
```

There is a relationship on person connecting it to petowner.

It would be easy if the join from `person` to `petowner` AND the join from `petowner` to `animal` were both inner joins or both outer joins. However, the join from `person` to `petowner` is an outer join and the join from `petowner` to `animal` is an inner join. To accomplish this, I added two `contains_eager` calls to the options.

Is this the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer:** *From what I can see, you should be using `outerjoin` for both, unless you do not want to see `Persons` who have no animals*.

**First**, Lets take a look at `JOIN`s:

- `both INNER`: in this case the result of your query will return **only** those `Person`s that have at least one animal (assuming that any `PetOwner.animal` is not nullable)
- `OUTER for PetOwner, INNER for Animal`: same as above (again, assuming that any `PetOwner.animal` is not nullable)
- `both OUTER`: the result of your query will return **all** `Person`s irrespective if they own an `Animal` or not

**Then**, what do `contains_eager` do? According to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager),

> ... will indicate to the query that the given attribute should be eagerly loaded from columns currently in the query.

What this means is that when you access the `Person.petowner_set`, not additional database query will be required, because the SA will will load the relationships from your original query. This has absolutely no impact of how your `JOINs` work, and only affects the loading of the relationships. This is simply a data loading optimization.

Comment: I should have specified more in my question. I was looking for the correct way to perform the data loading. I need the query to only call once and still be able to access the petowner_set and each petowner's pet. Doing this without data loading is fairly simple but then it turns into an n+1 query. I wasn't sure if my usage of contains_eager was done correctly. I originally tried outerjoin but I need one outerjoin, and one innerjoin as my query in the question was.

Comment: Why do you need an `innerjoin`?

Comment: Shucks, I meant to say I originally tried joinedload_all. My query had: joinedload_all("petowner_set.animal") which worked but made them all outerjoin. And as to why i need an inner join, the fk pet on petowner is a required field. A petowner cannot exist without a pet. So inner join is only logical. I'm not the best at optimizing but I'd assume an outerjoin is less efficient.

Comment: Yes, `innerjoin` is logical, but only if you look at `PetOwner->Pet` in isolation. However this `inner join` will filter out the `Person`s who do not have any animals. If this is what you want - great, if not - you need both joins to be `outer`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only difference is that you should chain the calls to `contains_eager`, like this:

```
q = (session.query(Person)
    .outerjoin(PetOwner)
    .join(Animal)
    .options(
      contains_eager("petowner_set").contains_eager("petowner_set.animal")
    )
)
```

see: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#controlling-loading-via-options